# Telerik Reporting Pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. Telerik Reporting has been chosen as the Tools of report generation. It's been a couple of days am challenging to generate a report. Here is the scenario:

There is a ReportModel class providing required properties to bind to the report.

```
public class NewReportModel
{
    public string ReprotTitle { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public double ReportSum { get; set; }
}
```

As shown above, there is a Generic List Property of Property which must be displayed in the details section with pagination, thus I must use a TextBox control as Table does not support pagination. (According to what I have gained from surfing the web and Telerik Blogs).

The **ReportTitle** prop should also shown at the top of every page, and **ReportSum** at the bottom of every page of the report.

On the other hand, I apply an **ObjectDataSource** and its **DataMember** returns an instance of type **NewReportModel**. The Report Designer DataSource is bound to the mentioned ObjectDataSource. Up to here, I can have the ReportTitle and ReportSum props shown on the Report.

**The problem is that, How Can I have list of products displayed on the report viewer with pagination?**

I tried to use table and bind its DataSource to the List and so Bind the table TextBox expression to "=Fields.Name". But this is not what needed as it brings no pagination. I also tried to use SubReport but again no pagination.

I explicitly mean HTML pagination, The ReportViewer control pagination and not the Export PDF pagination.

How can I come over this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Ali,

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer on my own, hope it helps the others too:

```
private void TheSecondReport_ItemDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reportParamTitle = new ReportParameter
                              {
                                  Name = "Title",
                                  Value = "Report Title",
                                  Type = ReportParameterType.String
                              };
        var reportParamSummation = new ReportParameter
        {
            Name = "Summation",
            Value = 46464646,
            Type = ReportParameterType.Integer
        };

        textBox2.Value = reportParamTitle.Value as string;
        textBox3.Value = reportParamSummation.Value.ToString();
    }
```